# How do I concisely check whether a string equals any of several values?

Tags: delphi

I currently have one record (with various values) and three user constants with specific assigned values (e.g. names, etc.).

I can compare an edit box against one user like this:

```
if edit1.text = user1 
 then xxxx
```

This is all well, but how do I specify that the edit box must check between the three different users?

Example:

```
if edit1.text = user1 to user3
 then xxxx
```

How Do I go about doing this?

Comment: wiping out your question like that will likely attract downvotes and your reputation score may go negative. If you weren't happy with your question rewrite it for the benefit of those who may come later.

Comment: StackOverflow is different both in philosophy and how it works to other forums you've used. I recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting again. Number one principle is that you're writing questions and answers not just for yourself, but for those who come after you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi doesn't support the use of strings in `case` statements so you have to do it the hard way.

```
 if ((user1.name = edit1.text) and (user1.surname = edit2.text)) or 
    ((user2.name = edit1.text) and (user2.surname = edit2.text)) or 
    ((user3.name = edit1.text) and (user3.surname = edit2.text)) 
   then xxxx
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do what I want to do in my original post (in the edit)?

Comment: Yes with a few extra brackets otherwise it won't be evaluated correctly.

Comment: Hard as in many more keystrokes than if you were working with integers where you could make use of "case" and "in" statements.

Comment: @wannabecoder, I recommend you take a look at these sites if you haven't found them already http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal and http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks it was relevant, just don't need it anymore and I can't wipe

Comment: Well you've made it a target for the moderators so it will definitely be wiped soon. You can also expect a few downvotes before that happens too.

Comment: Multiple reuse of `edit1.text` is not a good idea. This property is slow, using a GDI message for each time its getter is excecuted. You should rather use a temporary string then compare to values.

Answer (score 10):

Recent versions of Delphi (I use XE) have unit StrUtils.pas which contains

```
function MatchText(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Boolean;
function MatchStr(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Boolean;
```

MatchStr is the case sensitive version.

Your problem can now be solved like this:

```
if MatchStr(edit1.text, [user1, user2, user3])
  then xxxx
```

Comment: +1 Excellent, a solution using both open arrays and built in RTL functions

Comment: @Marjan: surely they are in D2007 - and IIRC they were introduced much earlier, they should be present in D7 already.

Comment: @Idsandon: oh dear, I really should start comparing the source trees like a colleague of mine does...

Comment: There are a lot of little known RTL functions in Delphi. And when the help system became less complete and practical to use it's even harder to find them

Answer (score 3):

You can use AnsiMatchStr()/AnsiMatchText() to check if a string matches one of the string in an array. AnsiIndexStr()/AnsiIndexText() also return the index of the matched string, and thereby can be useful in *case of* statements.

Comment: +1 I'd add that the AnsiMatchStr/Text functions are the locale specific equivalents of MatchStr/Text.

Answer (score 2):

For a set which might grow later at runtime, I might declare a TStringList, if I have a class instance to hold the "acceptable values" and replace the large `if (x=a1) or (x=a2) or (x=a3)....` sequence with:

```
 // FAcceptableValues is TStringList I set up elsewhere, such as my class constructor.
 if FAcceptableValues.IndexOf(x)>=0 then ...
```

That has the benefit of being customizeable. In the case of your logic, I would consider making a list of controls, and doing a Match function:

```
 var 
   Users:TList<TUser>;
   Edits:TList<TEdit>;
 begin
    ... other stuff like setup of FUsers/FEdits.
    if Match(Users,Edits) then ...
```

Match could be written as a simple for next loop:

```
 For U in Users do 
     for E in Edits do
          if U.Text=E.Text then 
            begin 
             result := true;
             exit
            end;
```

Comment: String list seems pretty heavyweight for this

Comment: Is there an echo in here? :-)